# Java: How to read from current offset when I start reading from a kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using Java api consumer connector . Whenever consumer starts reading from a topic, it reads from the beginning of a topic and it takes quite a while to catch up with latest event. How can we make sure that consumer reads from the current offset ?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to disable auto-commit (ie, `auto.commit.enable=false`), and use `auto.offset.reset=latest` (or `=largest` for older Kafka versions) in your consumer configuration.

The flow in Kafka is as follows:

1. start consumer
2. consumer looks for a valid committed offse

   - if found, it resumes processing from there
   - if not found, start processing according to "auto.offset.reset"

Thus, as long as there is a valid committed offset for your consumer group, "auto.offset.reset" has no effect at all. Therefore, you should also not commit manually.

If there is already a committed offset, you need to delete it manually, before restarting your consumer if you want to read from current offset and not process and old data. (Or use a new `group.id` for which you know that there is no committed offset.)

As an alternative to all this, you can also "seek to end" of each partition in your consumer. But this makes your code more complex and can be avoided if no commit happens for your consumer group at all.

Comment: why we should not commit manually? when will commit happen if we don't do it manually. I tried setting (auto.commit.enable=false) and uto.offset.reset=largest and have the same group id as before, but it is still reading from the beginning.

Comment: Updated my answer. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

for kafka 9:

1. if you set group id for your consumer, kafka will store committed (processed) offsets for you. This works if you use new consumer in kafka
   [read more](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example)
2. if you always want to read from latest offset, you can specify OffsetResetStrategy.LATEST

Comment: OffsetResetStrategy will be ignored if you have stored offset already

Answer (score 1):

For kafka 0.10 (and possibly earlier) you can do this:

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
consumer.seekToEnd(Collections.emptySet());
```

This turns off storing the consumer offset on the brokers (since you're not using it) and seeks to the latest position of all partitions.

Comment: You may add that it is necessary to use a consumer group that did not already commit the read offset.

Comment: True it won't remove any existing stored offset. However wouldn't using seek just override this?
I realised the OP didn't define what she means by "current offset". My answer assumes she wants latest published.  If she meant "latest consumed" then auto commit needs to be enabled and the consumer group name needs to be the same on every run.

Answer (score 0):

To complete Natalia's answer I'd say that you probably don't care about storing offsets, you just want to always consume latest messages.

To achieve that behavior using most consumer implementations (including "old" consumer in 0.8.x and "new" consumer in 0.9.x and above) you'll need to do 2 things:

1. Set group ID to a random value, this way each time your consumer starts it won't be able to restore offsets from anywhere and this will trigger the "offset reset" request.
2. Set `OffsetRequestStrategy` (or whatever it is called in the client you use) to `latest`, so that when your client asks for available offset from Kafka it gets the offset for the last (newest) message in the log.

Comment: If the OP is not interested in storing offsets, would it not be better to use `KafkaConsumer.assign()` instead of `subscribe()` and then just `seekToEnd()`?

Comment: Maybe but then he would need to get partitions to assign himself

Comment: @serejja Yes i tried setting group id to new name and (auto.offset.reset=largest) . It worked. But I had some existing consumers and I wanted same group id for all of them. Can't we fix the issue of we have same group id?